# How to access the data attributes of one-to-many relationship?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models defined:

```
App.Folder = DS.Model.extend({
    items: DS.hasMany('item', { async: true }),
    name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
    folder: DS.belongsTo('folder'),
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I want to be able to display the name of the folder for a given item, but when I try the following:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="item">
    <h1>{{item.folder.name}}</h1>
</script>
```

nothing appears?

How can I display the data attributes of a one-to-many relationship?

Comment: How are you load data for this models? Could you provide more information about data-layer from your application?

Comment: Solved my problem. The dataset used `folderID: 6` as an attribute, when it should be `folder: 6`.